# Is possible to edit "ionic-img-viewer" npm or copy the image style in Ionic 2?

Tags: image, css, npm, ionic2

I want to ask if I can to edit or add any additions when my image viewed by "ionic-img-viewer" npm. Or at least how can used the same style of my image tag.

for example: this is my img tag and you can see some codes of filters

```
<img src="{{url}}" style="filter: brightness(130%) contrast(130%) grayscale(100%) ;" #imageToView>
```

These codes of using ionic-img-viewer npm

```
<button ion-button full clear icon-only color="" (click)="viewImg(imageToView)">
   <ion-icon name="expand"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

TS codes

```
import { ImageViewerController } from "ionic-img-viewer";
...
constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, ..., public imageViewerCtrl: ImageViewerController)   
... 
viewImg(imageToView) {
  const viewer = this.imageViewerCtrl.create(imageToView)
  viewer.present();
}
```

When I viewed this image with ionic-img-viewer it's show me the original image (without any filter). So is there any way to applied my style in the viewed image.

> Note: ionic-img-viewer npm is this [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-img-viewer ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just searched to javascript files of npm in

> ..\node_modules\ionic-img-viewer\dist\umd\src\image-viewer.component.js
>   ..\node_modules\ionic-img-viewer\dist\es2015\src\image-viewer.component.js

Then playing with template code as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: Note that modifying a package is discouraged because you will definitely lose these changes if you tried to build you application on a different machine or instance. Better thing would be copying the package files in your application directory and making your modification.

Comment: The edited files already inside my application folders and I checked to upload it to see the results and it works fine

Comment: But the path you are mentioning is `node_modules`

Comment: I'm not sure about this point 100%. But ionic2 creates this folder and all npm or any other additions will be stored in this folder. So as I think no problem if u changed some parts of codes there. Any way, I will try to search about this thing more.

Comment: Yes, there are parts of the application that are ignored from the version control system you are using (git) because it can be downloaded from the package registry. If you are not using version control you can ignore my comment

Comment: I have the same issue, but I don't want to modify the module source code, can I extend the module and include the custom template? How?